# how to use Calc2LaTeX

Tags: tables, open-office, excel2latex

I've installed extension Calc2LaTeX to convert OO tables into LATEX. But I don't see any extra button on OO to get LATEX CODE;

In Extension manage of OO, it's showing Calc2Latex in Enabled format.

Can you please help me to understand, how to get Latex code for Open office excel?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's fairly easy. Open any spreadsheet and select the rows/columns you want to appear in your table.
Go to "Extras / Execute Macro / My Macros/Calc2Latex". Click on "Main" in the right side and "execute". It can take a few seconds before you will see the LaTeX dialogue which will allow you further settings.

(I hope the menu wording is similar in OpenOffice: I am using the German version of LibreOffice 4.1)

[image: Macrodialogue]

Comment: I can not find it. I am using English debian 8.4 with libreoffice 4.3.3.2. I can get the window shown above via Tools → Macros → run macro… (this is mostly as described as above, except minor translation changes), however I do not have calc2latex in my macros.

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2016 **Calc2LaTeX** was working fine. I used it as explained by [*@blue_tiger300*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23255/blue-tiger300) in 2014. Also there is a good anonymous *how to use* mini tutorial at the end of the comments in the [open office extensions page](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/comment/754#comment-754) for this macro.

Make sure your table is in Calc because it does not work to convert a table from Open Office Writer to LaTeX.

I checked the alternative package **odsfile** mentioned in the follow up answer and it looks very interesting, however its philosophy is to import and format targeted content from an external spreadsheet file at compile time via macros. Just my personal preference is to have full LaTeX source for my tables.
In my opinion **Calc2Latex** remains the fastest and cleanest way to quickly convert spreadsheet tables into LaTeX code independently of the desktop operating system as this would work in a Mac, Windows, or Linux distro.

Just for reference I used the following program versions:

- Libre Office Calc Version: 4.2.8.2, Build ID: 420m0(Build:2)
- LaTeX IDE: TexStudio 2.11.2 (hg 6190:053ffdf7915b) Using Qt Version 5.2.1, compiled with Qt 5.2.1 R
- TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015)
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: In 2020, this macro is still going strong.

Comment: Good to know Hermann, I use it quite often!

Comment: This is an awesome option I just found: [latex-tables.com](https://www.latex-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It could well be that the package `calc2latex` is no longer working at all. It was unmaintained in 2014 already.
There is however another package that works even better, [odsfile](http://ctan.org/pkg/odsfile), which has many more features.
The only 'drawback' is that it depends on lualatex.