# Can we let Tex/Latex compiler read tables from excel/word/pdf file automatically?

Tags: table-of-contents

My concern is to automatically read table contents, instead of handling this problem by using other off-line tools. Just like we can use eps figure in pdflatex by using the package "epstopdf".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Word or Excel tables to Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246025/converting-word-or-excel-tables-to-latex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for something like [`excel2latex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex). A package that convert Excel spreadsheets to LaTeX tables.

However, I find better the [tablesgenerator](http://tablesgenerator.com/) online tool. Even if it could be tedious to manually set each option it offers a better control of the layout of the table. It also offer the possibility to import data from `.csv` files if you have a lot of data entries.

In any case, all of this is already been said in [Converting Word or Excel tables to Latex](http://Converting%20Word%20or%20Excel%20tables%20to%20Latex).

Comment: Personally I find a better choice to manually include the data, if not too much, with [tablesgenerator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148003)

Comment: @HenriMenke. In general I would agree with you however in this case the link point to the package itself on CTAN. If the link will be broken will mean that the package will no longer be available officially. Even obsolete packages are still there on CTAN, if a package is deleted from CTAN it's better to don't download it.

Comment: @HenriMenke. However I agree that maybe I should put some more infos.