# Excel2Latex Macros issues Mac Excel 2011

Tags: tables, macros, mac, excel, excel2latex

I'm trying to get Excel2Latex to work on my Mac but I always get the same error message: When I try to open the file, excel warns me that the workbook contains macros and gives me the open to enable or disable macros. When I disable them, two tabs appear, one of them says "convert table to latex". When I click it though, it gives me an error message: "macros are disabled...". However, when I open the file and choose "enable macros" the two tabs don't show up at all, so that I can't convert anything.
Any idea how I can solve this?
Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This does not really seem on-topic here as it is about MS software...

Comment: @TeXnician Well, it's about getting LaTeX code out of an Excel tabular. Don't be so trigger happy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install [LibreOffice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179222) and the [calc2latex](https://extensions.openoffice.org/node/1752) macro package.

Open your file in LibreOffice calc and export a LaTeX tabular. How to: see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179222 .